# Android Room increase connection pool limit

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

is it possible to increase the connection pool limit for Android Room?

I keep getting this error:

```
SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for database '/data/...' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 1250 (arch_disk_io_1) with flags 0x2 for 30.001001 seconds.
    Connections: 0 active, 1 idle, 1 available.
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I faced the same on samsung device

Answer (score 0):

Have you perhaps tried executing `endTransaction()` inside the `finally` block of transaction?

Comment: I'm using the same room database object over multiple worker instances with one 'big' transaction. Sometimes it's working and sometimes not and then I'm getting this error.